# check if each element of array is null and throw an error if so

Tags: arrays, validation, null

How to check if all elements of a array are null instead of doing a foreach through each element. Is there a method in .Net 4.0 which we can make use of? Thanks in advance.

```
    e.g. 



Outputs[0] = null
outputs[1] = null
Outputs[2] = null
outputs[3] = null
Outputs[4] = null
outputs[5] = null
Outputs[6] = null
outputs[7] = null
Outputs[8] = null
outputs[9] = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bool allNull = Outputs.All(element => element == null)`

But this just hides the foreach in a method call.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response and sorry for delayed response. I have implemented in slightly different way. Like so. if (Outputs != null && !Array.TrueForAll(Outputs, value => { return value != null; })).